# AVAssetWriter finishWriting failure when CTCallStateIncoming

Tags: recording, avassetwriter

I use AVAssetWriter AVCaptureSession to recording video.it work well.I use UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification and CTCallCenter.callEventHandler to stop record when Application goes background or a call come in.UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification works well.But in CTCallCenter.callEventHandler,[AVAssetWriter finishWriting] return NO . here is AVAssetWriter.error:

Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "这项操作无法完成" UserInfo=0x6c0bc20 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=发生未知错误（-12785）, NSUnderlyingError=0x6c0fc80 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12785.)", NSLocalizedDescription=这项操作无法完成}

It seems AVAssetWriter failed immediately when a call coming.The recorded file not finished and can't be played.Can someone tell me how to do with it?

CTCallCenter code:

```
    m_callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
    m_callCenter.callEventHandler= ^(CTCall* call)
    {
        if (call.callState == CTCallStateDialing || call.callState == CTCallStateIncoming){
            [self stopRecording];
            //[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopRecording) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
    };
```

stopRecording work fine in other case.

Answer (score 6):

Phone calls cause `AudioSession` interruptions, so you might find out sooner if you use the `AudioSession` callback. Although I suspect your `AVAssetWriter` may already be fried at this point.

Setting `AVAssetWriter.movieFragmentInterval` should help minimize your loss - from AVAssetWriter.h:

> When movie fragments are used, a partially written asset whose writing
>   is unexpectedly interrupted can be successfully opened and played up
>   to multiples of the specified time interval.

Comment: I add this line in my code: 
 _videoWriter.movieFragmentInterval = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0, 1000000000);
And it works fine.Although finishWriting return NO,but the movie file can be played.Thank you.

Comment: That's a very small fragment interval, personally I'd try something a little larger, say 1s or more. P.S. it's good practice to accept answers that answer your question.